# javascript carousel does not work

Tags: javascript, html, image, carousel

I am currently doing a project that is similar to this http://www.agilecarousel.com/carousel_example.htm, but using the codes that was provided it doesn't work for me I have included all the paths neened.Can you provide me with some solutions or suggestion on how to do image carousel?

This is my current code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="smplecarousel/agile_carousel.css" type='text/css'>
   <div class="slideshow" id="multiple_slides_visible"></div>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="smplecarousel/agile_carousel.a1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $.getJSON("smplecarousel/agile_carousel_data.php", function(data) {
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#multiple_slides_visible").agile_carousel({
                carousel_data: data,
                carousel_outer_height: 230,
                carousel_height: 200,
                slide_height: 200,
                carousel_outer_width: 480,
                slide_width: 160,
                number_slides_visible: 3,
                transition_time: 330,
                control_set_1: "previous_button,next_button",
                control_set_2: "group_numbered_buttons",
                persistent_content: "<p class='persistent_content'>Agile Carousel Example: Multiple Slides Visible</p>"       
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You need php to get this to work.

Comment: Yhea this a php page, I do also have a page for my smplecarousel/agile_carousel_data.php where all of my pictures are stored.

Comment: Is your php page talking back to the script? .. Did you check your console to see if any errors pop up?